# Blazor and Bootstrap 5 Floating labels

Tags: blazor, bootstrap-5

Using Blazor I migrated to bootstrap 5 and want to use [Floating labels](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/floating-labels/) with standard Blazor `<InputNumber @bind-Value="FooModel.FooValue" />`.

I'm trying combinations like:

```html
<div class="form-floating">
    <InputNumber type="number" class="form-control" id="floatingInput" placeholder="name@example.com" @bind-Value="FooModel.FooValue" />
    <label for="floatingInput">Test blazor</label>
</div>
```

but it's not working. Any ideas?

EDIT-------------------

Ok, I founded my own bug - FooModel.FooValue was not nullable int type, so on View 0 was displayed as default;

Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

It works. Which part of it is not working for you?
Try
@bind-Value="@FooModel.FooValue"
instead of
@bind-Value="FooModel.FooValue"

Assuming FooModel is the variable name and NOT class name.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I founded my own bug - FooModel.FooValue was not nullable int type, so on View 0 was displayed as default;

Thanks anyway